# Iterate over object(s) if present, single or plural

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say that i have object **my_obj**

and i get this object from database, with some more calculation, it doesn't matter...

and then i need to iterate via such object, like:

```
my_obj.each do |m|
 some_method(m.id)
end
```

this code is not good, becouse if my_obj is nil, i will get error like:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

so i decide to write:

```
  if my_obj.present?
    my_obj.each do |m|
     some_method(m.id)
    end
  end
```

but i think that there is one more way of doing this, without writting everywhere if construction.

so how could i iterate via object, only if it is not null?

Comment: 'object' implies singular, 'objects' is plural. You can't iterate a singular object.

Comment: @BillyChan i know, how in such case i could do...

Comment: and how come you have `nil` instead of `[]` if it's a collection? you're shadowing a problem somewhere else, I am afraid.

Comment: @tokland listen, my_obj = Article.all, let's say so...

Comment: @brabertaser1992 `Article.all` never returns `nil`. If there are no records, an empty collection is returned, i.e. `[]`

Answer (score 6):

I found the code a bit anti-pattern for normal OOP principle "Tell, Don't ask".  I tried the question in console and found your worry unnecessary.

No matter what the result is, blank Array or blank ActiveRecord::Relation object, `each` all works and return a blank array `[]`.

```
Article.count
# => 0

articles = Article.all # Return array in Rails 3
articles.each { |a| puts a.title }
# => []

articles = Article.scoped # Return ActiveRecord::Relation object in Rails 3
articles.each { |a| puts a.title }
# => []
```

I would suggest you to review the method and returned result of your query. If your query returns unusual things, make sure it returns at least a blank Array. Then you don't need to consider too much.

Answer (score 5):

They easiest way to handle this is to surround your object with the 'Array' conversion function which will coerce your possibly nil input into an array while leaving an existing array untouched, e.g.

```
>> Array(nil)
=> []
```

and

```
>> Array([1])
=> [1]
```

So in your case:

```
Array(my_obj).each do |m|
 some_method(m.id)
end
```

Comment: Not that [`Kernel::Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) also turns scalars into arrays: `Array(1)` => `[1]`.

Comment: Right, it's very handy for methods that could accept an array or a scalar. i.e. def my_method(scalar_or_array) arr = Array(scalar_or_array)

Answer (score 3):

The collection query should always return iterable object, but there are several ways. The problem of `nil` checks led to a pattern named [NullObjects](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/) which is often the best solution. Apart from that you can do:

```
my_object.to_a.each do |m|
  some_method(m.id)
end
```

or

```
my_object.try(:each) do |m|
  some_method(m.id)
end
```

or

```
(my_object || []).each do |m|
  some_method(m.id)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In Rails, you can do [`Object#try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method:

```
my_object.try(:each) do |m|
  some_method(m.id)
end
```

It will call `each` (returning its result) with attached block if `my_object` is other than `nil`. Otherwise, it won't call `each` method and will return `nil`.

Comment: @brabertaser1992 It's unlikely there's something shorter and more elegant to achieve your goal.

Comment: I think your solution is the most logical, since the "try" method has been designed for this exact kind of case. Besides, it also has the advantage to return nil if my_object is nil.
However, in pratice, I prefer the solution of Phlip, with which you know that your object is always an enumerable and you can apply all the enumerable methods on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize like this;

```
def fields_each(fields)
  if fields.present? && fields.keys.present?
    fields.each do |key, value|
      yield(key, value) if block_given?
    end
  end
end
```

and usage;

```
fields_each({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}) do |key, value|
  puts "Key: #{key} value: #{value}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone forgot the awesome `[my_objects].flatten.compact`!

Answer (score 1):

in the newer ruby version, tested with `2.4.1`, this can be written as

```
my_obj&.each do |m|
 some_method(m.id)
end
```

Comment: Anybody needing a bit more context on the ampersand and what id does: http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

when you initialize the `my_obj` do it like this

```
my_obj = Model.all || [] # Empty array will not iterate or throw error
```

**Ex:**

```
[].each do |x|
  p "I will not execute"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this above the loop:

```
   if my_obj == nil then
    redirect_to "something_else"
   end
```